# SQL, How to find changes in column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns, Date as DateTime and Value as INT(with 3 possible value 1,2,3)

The Table data is something like this:

```
Date                     , Value
---------------------------------------
2016-01-01 10:34:00                1
2016-01-01 10:35:00                1
2016-01-01 10:36:00                1
2016-01-01 10:37:00                1
2016-01-01 10:38:00                1
2016-01-01 10:39:00                3
2016-01-01 10:40:00                3
2016-01-01 10:41:00                2
2016-01-01 10:42:00                2
2016-01-01 10:43:00                2
2016-01-01 10:44:00                1
2016-01-01 10:45:00                1
2016-01-01 10:46:00                1
2016-01-01 10:47:00                1
```

I need a Sql Query(specially in MySQL) to generate output:

```
Start Date              ,  End Date            , value
---------------------------------
2016-01-01 10:34:00     , 2016-01-01 10:38:00  , 1
2016-01-01 10:39:00     , 2016-01-01 10:40:00  , 3
2016-01-01 10:41:00     , 2016-01-01 10:43:00  , 2
2016-01-01 10:44:00     , 2016-01-01 10:47:00  , 1
```

is it possible?
please help. thank you

Comment: Are you always going to want this ordered by the date like in your example?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is with variables.  You need to define a grouping parameter, which changes each time the value changes:

```
select min(date), max(date), value
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@v = value, @grp,
                         if(@v := value, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from t cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @v := -1) params
      order by date
     ) t
group by grp, value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one more

```
SELECT min(my_date), max(my_date), val
FROM (
  SELECT @nr := IF(@old_val = val, @nr, @nr := @nr +1) AS nr
  , @old_val := val
  , t.* 
  FROM onoff t
    ,(SELECT @nr:=0, @old_val='') AS tmp
  ORDER BY my_date
  ) AS t1
  GROUP BY nr
  ORDER BY min(my_date);
```

**The Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `onoff` (
  `my_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `val` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`my_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `onoff` (`my_date`, `val`)
VALUES
    ('2016-01-01 10:34:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-01 10:35:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-01 10:36:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-01 10:37:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-01 10:38:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-01 10:39:00', 3),
    ('2016-01-01 10:40:00', 3),
    ('2016-01-01 10:41:00', 2),
    ('2016-01-01 10:42:00', 2),
    ('2016-01-01 10:43:00', 2),
    ('2016-01-01 10:44:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-01 10:45:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-01 10:46:00', 1),
    ('2016-01-01 10:47:00', 1);
```